# (Unity 5.6) (IBM Watson SDK) Parsing user speech into text and then back into speech

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, speech-to-text, watson

I'm trying to use the new [IBM Watson SDK for Unity] to take user's speech input, parse it into text, and then pass that text back to watson's text to speech so that it can repeat what the user said.

Already I've used the SDK's [Speech To Text widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV3pb.png)[takes audio clip from microphone and parses into text], in conjunction with it's [Speech display widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4wp.jpg) [takes text input from speech to text and displays it on canvas in scene] to display the users' speech on screen. I then created a UI input field, assosciated it with the SpeechDisplaywidget's text output- as well as a texttoSpeechWidget's input - And then made a UI button that, when clicked, sends the text to the text to speech service. It should play the assosciated text to speech file, but when I click the button, nothing happens. the 'status' display just reads "ready" and never changes, and the whole thing throws no errors. I'd paste code, but I haven't written any yet, just connected all the necessary serialized fields and hit go. What should I do?

Sorry for the vagueness, but as this is my first question, I can't post more pictures or links. :/

Here is the code for the "texttoSpeechWidget" that I am trying to utilize.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.TextToSpeech.v1;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.DataTypes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;

#pragma warning disable 414

namespace IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Widgets
{
  /// <summary>
  /// TextToSpeech widget class wraps the TextToSpeech serivce.
  /// </summary>
  [RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
  public class TextToSpeechWidget : Widget
  {
 #region Inputs
[SerializeField]
private Input m_TextInput = new Input("Text", typeof(TextToSpeechData), 
"OnTextInput");
[SerializeField]
private Input m_VoiceInput = new Input("Voice", typeof(VoiceData), 
"OnVoiceSelect");
#endregion

#region Outputs
[SerializeField]
private Output m_Speaking = new Output(typeof(SpeakingStateData), true);
[SerializeField]
private Output m_DisableMic = new Output(typeof(DisableMicData));
[SerializeField]
private Output m_LevelOut = new Output(typeof(LevelData));
#endregion

#region Private Data
TextToSpeech m_TextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech();

[SerializeField, Tooltip("How often to send level out data in seconds.")]
private float m_LevelOutInterval = 0.05f;
[SerializeField]
private float m_LevelOutputModifier = 1.0f;
[SerializeField]
private Button m_TextToSpeechButton = null;
[SerializeField]
private InputField m_Input = null;
[SerializeField]
private Text m_StatusText = null;
[SerializeField]
private VoiceType m_Voice = VoiceType.en_US_Michael;
[SerializeField]
private bool m_UsePost = false;

private AudioSource m_Source = null;
private int m_LastPlayPos = 0;

private class Speech
{
  ~Speech()
  {
    if (Clip != null)
      UnityObjectUtil.DestroyUnityObject(Clip);
  }

  public bool Ready { get; set; }
  public AudioClip Clip { get; set; }

  public Speech(TextToSpeech textToSpeech, string text, bool usePost)
  {
    textToSpeech.ToSpeech(text, OnAudioClip, usePost);
  }

  private void OnAudioClip(AudioClip clip)
  {
    Clip = clip;
    Ready = true;
  }

};

private Queue<Speech> m_SpeechQueue = new Queue<Speech>();
private Speech m_ActiveSpeech = null;
#endregion

#region Public Memebers

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the voice. Default voice is English, US - Michael
/// </summary>
/// <value>The voice.</value>
public VoiceType Voice
{
  get
  {
    return m_Voice;
  }
  set
  {
    m_Voice = value;
  }
}

#endregion

#region Event Handlers
/// <summary>
/// Button event handler.
/// </summary>
public void OnTextToSpeech()
{
  if (m_TextToSpeech.Voice != m_Voice)
    m_TextToSpeech.Voice = m_Voice;
  if (m_Input != null)
    m_SpeechQueue.Enqueue(new Speech(m_TextToSpeech, m_Input.text, m_UsePost));
  if (m_StatusText != null)
    m_StatusText.text = "THINKING";
  if (m_TextToSpeechButton != null)
    m_TextToSpeechButton.interactable = false;
}
#endregion

#region Private Functions
private void OnTextInput(Data data)
{
  TextToSpeechData text = data as TextToSpeechData;
  if (text == null)
    throw new WatsonException("Wrong data type received.");

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text))
  {
    if (m_TextToSpeech.Voice != m_Voice)
      m_TextToSpeech.Voice = m_Voice;

    m_SpeechQueue.Enqueue(new Speech(m_TextToSpeech, text.Text, m_UsePost));
  }
}

private void OnVoiceSelect(Data data)
{
  VoiceData voice = data as VoiceData;
  if (voice == null)
    throw new WatsonException("Unexpected data type");

  m_Voice = voice.Voice;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
  UnityObjectUtil.StartDestroyQueue();

  if (m_StatusText != null)
    m_StatusText.text = "READY";
}

/// <exclude />
protected override void Start()
{
  base.Start();
  m_Source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void Update()
{
  if (m_Source != null && !m_Source.isPlaying
      && m_SpeechQueue.Count > 0
      && m_SpeechQueue.Peek().Ready)
  {
    CancelInvoke("OnEndSpeech");

    m_ActiveSpeech = m_SpeechQueue.Dequeue();
    if (m_ActiveSpeech.Clip != null)
    {
      if (m_Speaking.IsConnected)
        m_Speaking.SendData(new SpeakingStateData(true));
      if (m_DisableMic.IsConnected)
        m_DisableMic.SendData(new DisableMicData(true));

      m_Source.spatialBlend = 0.0f;     // 2D sound
      m_Source.loop = false;            // do not loop
      m_Source.clip = m_ActiveSpeech.Clip;             // clip
      m_Source.Play();

      Invoke("OnEndSpeech", ((float)m_ActiveSpeech.Clip.samples / (float)m_ActiveSpeech.Clip.frequency) + 0.1f);
      if (m_LevelOut.IsConnected)
      {
        m_LastPlayPos = 0;
        InvokeRepeating("OnLevelOut", m_LevelOutInterval, m_LevelOutInterval);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Log.Warning("TextToSpeechWidget", "Skipping null AudioClip");
    }
  }

  if (m_TextToSpeechButton != null)
    m_TextToSpeechButton.interactable = true;
  if (m_StatusText != null)
    m_StatusText.text = "READY";
}

private void OnLevelOut()
{
  if (m_Source != null && m_Source.isPlaying)
  {
    int currentPos = m_Source.timeSamples;
    if (currentPos > m_LastPlayPos)
    {
      float[] samples = new float[currentPos - m_LastPlayPos];
      m_Source.clip.GetData(samples, m_LastPlayPos);
      m_LevelOut.SendData(new LevelData(Mathf.Max(samples) * m_LevelOutputModifier, m_LevelOutputModifier));
      m_LastPlayPos = currentPos;
    }
  }
  else
    CancelInvoke("OnLevelOut");
}
private void OnEndSpeech()
{
  if (m_Speaking.IsConnected)
    m_Speaking.SendData(new SpeakingStateData(false));
  if (m_DisableMic.IsConnected)
    m_DisableMic.SendData(new DisableMicData(false));
  if (m_Source.isPlaying)
    m_Source.Stop();

  m_ActiveSpeech = null;
}

/// <exclude />
protected override string GetName()
{
  return "TextToSpeech";
}
#endregion
```

}

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!! Can you post the code you tried ?

Comment: hello Alaa! thank you so much for responding! 

Like I said, I personally haven't written any code yet, but i have updated my post with the script for the "TextToSpeechWidget" ; '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to write a little code to achieve it.

1. Create a new widget using Widget class as base.
2. Place your input as SpeechToText and Output as TextToSpeech

   ```
   [SerializeField]
   private Input m_SpeechInput = new Input("Text", typeof(SpeechToTextData), "OnSpeech");
   [SerializeField]
   private Output m_SpeechOutput = new Output(typeof(TextToSpeechData), true);
   ```
3. Then you should add OnSpeech function into your widget to handle the conversation from SpeechToTextData to TextToSpeechData by creating a new object type of TextToSpeechData and using input SpeechToTextData's text (if it is final).
4. Use your output in OnSpeech like;

   ```
   if (m_SpeechOutput.IsConnected)
       m_SpeechOutput.SendData( /* object of type  SpeechToTextData*/ );
   ```

Make sure you have SpeechToTextWidget and TextToSpeechWidget are exists in the scene and they are both connected to this new widget.